# Error in Connecting to TFS Server(TF31001)

Tags: tfs, connection

I am unable to connect to the server which is located remotely and required connection to OpenVPN.
I would have concluded that its some sort of Authentication issue, but it seems that my teams mates using similar Working Environment to mine are able to establish connection. I am able to log in from their PC using my Credentials. Looks like this could be due to my local settings.

I have cleared the Cache as suggested in MSDN sites. Also, Firewall and Antivirus are off.

I also get prompted for the User/Name password when I click Team Explorer Icon on Visual Studio. Invalid credentials show error messages as expected, on entering proper credential information, I get the following message:

> TFS31001: Team Foundation cannot
>   retrieve the list of team projects
>   from Team Foundation Server. The Team
>   Foundation Server returned the
>   following error: Team Foundation
>   services are not available from the
>   server.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was problem at my end. Using a Different Gateway did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

That error message is always due to a security issue but that doesn't tell you "why" there is a security issue.  Can you take a look at the event log for more details- not sure what else might be in there but it might be a good starting point.

I had this issue a long time ago when working remotely and it was a trial and error thing but in my case clearing cache then removing the TFS Team Project and re-adding it fixed the issue.  You can try that.  I see you did clear cache but I am not sure from reading this if you removed and re-added.  If settings are cached and you dont do that I doubt you will see a change.

Another more aggressive solution would be to uninstall and reinstall Team Explorer.  Also, make sure your up to date on SPs.  Permissions could have been messed up somehow with TFS installation and this could potentially resolve the issue.

Anyway, I know this isn't a cut and dry answer but I hope it helps.  I just spent the last three days upgrading all our company Team Projects from 2008 to 2010 so I feel your pain :)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. Whether they eventually solve my issue or not, but there are several new steps to try on. From my part, I believe I am up to date with SPs. I did uninstall and reinstall everything, yet no luck :(. One thing haven't tried yet is to clear cache and then remove/readd. Will try that and keep my fingers crossed ;)

Comment: What I would do if I were you and none of this worked is also consider trying a different team explorer.  If you are using 2008, try installing 2010 and see if you can access it that way.  That would eliminate it being caused by some misc problem with a specific version of team explorer.  Yeah, hope you get it fixed up and gl.

Comment: Hey, not much luck :(. It didn't work :-s.
A bit more info: After removing the server, I restarted VS and got the message: "The Team Foundation Server[Server URL] is currently unavailable. Thie solution will be opened offline.". Why would this message come even after removing the server string.

Comment: Because inside of VS you set what your SourceSafe tool is.  You can disable it though by going to Tools > Options > Source Control > Current source control plug-in.

Comment: Did you try a different version of team explorer?

Comment: @NgM: No haven't tried a different version. But It's not free is it?

Comment: The System Admin at work tried out some steps and it was resolved. Turns out that it was Networking issue(usage of Gateway). I feel this question is too local and I am considering closing it.

Comment: At least you got it fixed up which is all that really matters and yeah I can see why you would close it out but it may be worth leaving at least as a troubleshooting guide for ppl.

Comment: Team Explorer is free btw.  You can use Team Explorer 2010 and run it against a 2008 TFS installation for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error once my TFS database server ran out of diskspace.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same error.

I found this which looked like a viable solution. :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/f681a2d6-eca9-4488-96a3-ed979a545a9b

I ended up just turning my proxy settings of in IE and it started working instantly.

Answer (score 0):

The same story occured with tfs 2012 - it was installed and configured properly, local network has domain and all users in domain correctly connected and worked with tfs projects.

But once the connection denied all tries for connection, all credentials were correct, but connections has been refused. Tried to configure tfs clients access, to reboot client machines... but worthless.

Only **server service/machine rebooting** helped. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by clearing the cache at:
C:\users{yourusername}\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation{version e.g.3.0}\Cache

Quit any open instance of visual studio first.